# Animating uitextfield when user begins editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uitextfield

I have the text field at the bottom of the screen. When the user taps it, the text field should animate up allowing room for the keyboard such as the iOS message app does. Anyway when this occurs, the animation is not happening correctly. Instead of going to where I specify (160, 410), It goes off the screen and right back on and then goes to where I specify. This causes it to look delayed and the keyboard goes up first. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    textField1.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
 {
     [dock setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 410)];
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     [dock setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 410)];
 }];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: are you using auto layout / layout constraints?

Comment: No I am not using them

Comment: I am not really familiar with that "old" syntax of doing animations - have you tried utilizing the block-way: `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`

Comment: No I have not but I can try that

Comment: I think that may only be for swift though because it says that property is not found for UIView

Comment: it is there for both: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:completion:

Comment: It suggests that syntax that you stated above but how would you completely write that with the UIView and everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using a transform, where in the same UIView.animateWithDuration block you say

```
dock.tranform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y)
```

Where x and y are the distance you want the doc to move.

See [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation) for more information.

Comment: Sorry this is in swift, I do not know objective-C very well

Answer (score 1):

Use the new syntax like this. Does it work?

```
   - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^
        {
            [dock setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 410)];
        }
    completion:^(BOOL finished)
        {
            //Implement completion method here.
        }];

        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: No it is doing exactly what my original animation did. It takes the view off the screen for a split second and back on. It doesn't move it to where I specify (160, 410)

Comment: what object is dock?.

Comment: does it jump off screen and come back when you don't animate it?

Comment: No only when I do animate it. So for some reason the animation is it jumping off and on

Comment: can you try animating the `frame` property instead? What happens?

Comment: The frame instead of center?

Comment: yes. Modifying the center property changes the frame anyway. I am wondering if it somehow messes up the origin.

Comment: did you set the `contentMode` to UIViewContentModeRedraw?

Comment: How do you set the contentMode?

Comment: [Take a look here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode)

Comment: It didn't change anything

Comment: sorry I am out of ideas. I could take a look if you put up a sample on github.

Comment: Ok. I could do that I suppose